# NameError: name is not defined web scraper

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to build a simple webscraper of ESG data for S&P500 companies but for some reason I keep getting NameError:

`name 'web_scraper' is not defined`

Tried a few things now but cannot get it to work. I'm a beginner so must be overlooking something. Thanks in advance

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact

def get_tickers():
 # wiki_page = requests.get()
  sp_data = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
  ticker_df = sp_data[0]
  ticker_options = ticker_df['Symbol']
  return ticker_options

  def level(x):
    if x == 0.0:
        return 'No Controversy'
    elif x == 1.0:
        return 'Little Controversy'
    elif x == 2.0: 
        return 'Moderate Controversy'
    elif x == 3.0: 
        return 'Relatively High Controversy'
    else:
        return 'Little Controversy'

    def web_scraper(ticker):
        elements = []
        web_data = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+ticker+'+/sustainability?p='+ticker).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(web_data, 'html.parser')
        esg_score = soup.find('div', {'class':'Fz(36px) Fw(600) D(ib) Mend(5px)'})
        datapoint = esg_score.text
        controversy_score = soup.find('div', {'class':'D(ib) Fz(36px) Fq(500)'})
        controversy_datapoint = controversy_score.text
        scores = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'D(ib) Fz(23px) smartphone_Fz(22px) Fq(600)'})
        for score in scores:
            elements.append(score.text)

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Total ESG Score': datapoint,
                   'Environment Score': elements[0],
                   'Social Score': elements[0],
                  'Governance Score': elements[2],
                 'Controversy Score': controversy_datapoint},
                  index = [ticker])
    df = df.astype('float')
    df['Controversy Assessment'] = df.apply(lambda x: level(x['Controversy Score']), axis=1)
    return df

@interact
def get_esg(ticker=widgets.Dropdown(description='Ticker',
                                      options=get_tickers(),
                                    value = 'F')):
  esg_data = web_scraper(ticker)
  return esg_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your indentation, `def web_scraper` is defined in `def level`, which is defined inside `def get_tickers`. So, if you want to be able to access `web_scraper` from anywhere, you have to define it in global scope, not just within the scope of another function (which is itself within yet another function).

Comment: Thank you Random Davis. It did fix the issue I was having. When I run the code right now I get `Indexerror: list index out of range` for the elements in the df. Any chance you see why that is the case?

Comment: @toost since that's a separate question, you can just make a new post, it's fine. You're meant to ask only one question per post.